# TotalTime of a stream - Video Flash Player AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, stream, netstream

Goodmorning,

I'm working on a video flash player to stream. What I want to do, is to display the total time of the stream and not the time since the user is watching the stream.
I have a problem now, is that when I pause then play the video, the current time restarts.
Do you have any ideas to fix my problem and to solve the other one? :)

**I'm using NetStream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, for the first problem, what you want to do is to setup a function that receives the MetaData of the video and save that value somewhere.

First, when you create your NetStream Object, you need to add a Client to the NetStream that references the function onMetaData.

```
var ns:NetStream;   //your NetStream Object
var client:Object = new Object(); //Create an Object that represents the client
client.onMetaData = onMetaData; //reference the function that catches the MetaData of the Video
ns.client = client;             //assign our client Object to the client property of the NetStream
                                //Once MetaData is available, it'll call onMetaData with all of the information

function onMetaData(metaData:Object):void
{
    duration = metaData.duration;   //duration is the variable that is supposed to total length of the video
}
```

Now with the `duration` value you get the total play time of the movie that is currently playing with that NetStream Object.

---

You can solve your second problem in a number of ways, for example:

- pause() and resume()
- pause() and player('currentTime')

Simply keep a `Boolean` Variable called pause that keeps track if the video is currently playing or not.

```
var paused:Boolean = false;  //assuming the video is currently playing
var currentTime:Number = 0;  
var button:Button;    //some kind of play/pause button
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onButtonClick);

function onButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(paused)
    {
        paused = false;
        ns.resume();
        //ns.play(currentTime)   //this also works
    }
    else
    {
        paused = true;
        ns.pause();
        currentTime = ns.time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the information from the meta data of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you answers :).

DodgerThud, I tried your solution concerning my second problem this morning. I tried your solution and I've got this : duration : NaN. If I understand well, my problem is that I don't have the metadata of the stream...

```
if(isLiveStream == false) {
            if(title == preroll || Number(duree) <= 0) {
                duration=infoObject.duration+timeOffset;
            } else {
                duration=Number(duree);
            }
        }
```

Those lines are on the onMetaData function.

Thank you for helping me.
Have a nice day.